# Sencha Touch 2: Dataview and Back Button not working

Tags: sencha-touch-2

i have a list of tweet inside of component Ext.dataView.DataView. Clicking into an item of list, it open one container that containe the detail of tweet. This cointainer is formed with toolbar (with title and back button), with information of tweet and with a map that contain the position of user of tweet. The back button should return back to the list but not working. How resolve that?

This is a code:

'TweetList'

```
Ext.define('TwitterSearch.view.TweetList', {    extend: 'Ext.dataview.DataView',
xtype: 'tweetlist',
requires: [
    'TwitterSearch.view.TweetListItem',
    'Ext.plugin.PullRefresh',
    'Ext.plugin.ListPaging',
    'TwitterSearch.view.contact.Show'
],


config: {
    ui           : 'timeline',
    defaultType  : 'tweetlistitem',
    allowDeselect: false,
    useComponents: true,
    emptyText: 'No tweets found.',
    itemTpl: ['TwitterSearch.view.contact.Show'],


    plugins: [
        'pullrefresh',
        {
            type: 'listpaging',
            autoPaging: true
        }
    ],


    items: [
        {
            docked: 'top',
            xtype : 'toolbar',
            hidden: true,
            ui    : 'searchbar',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    ui   : 'back',
                    text : 'Searches'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
initialize: function(obj, eOpts) {
    this.callParent();
  }});
```

'Show alias TweetDetail'

```
Ext.define('TwitterSearch.view.contact.Show', {
extend : 'Ext.Container',
xtype : 'contact-show',
requires: [ 'Ext.Map'],


config : {
    store: 'Tweet',
    title : 'Information',
    baseCls : 'x-show-contact',
    layout : 'vbox',
    items : [
             {
             xtype: 'toolbar',
             docked: 'top',
             title: 'Tweets Detail',

             items: [
                     {
                         xtype: 'button',
                         text: 'Back',
                         ui: 'back',
                         id: 'tweetDetailBackButton'
                     }
                 ]





            },{
                id : 'contenuto',
                tpl : [ 
                        '<div class="header">',
                        '<div class="avatar"><img src="../resources/images/default_profile_6_bigger.jpeg" /></div>',             
                        '<h3>Nome: {nomeutente}</h3>',
                        '<h4>Tweet: {tweet} </h4>',
                        '</div>',

                        '<p>Descrizione:{descrizione}</p>',
                        '<p>Lingua:{lingua}</p>',
                        '<p>Et&#225:{eta}</p>',
                        '<p>Nazione:{country}, Citt&#225:{city}</p>',
                        //'<p>Nazione:{country}</p>',            
                        //'<p>Citt&#225:{city}</p>',
                        '<p>Latitudine:{latitude},Longitudine:{longitude}</p>',
                        //'<p>Id Utente:{id_utente}</p>',
                        //'<p>Id Luogo:{id_luogo}</p>',

                        ].join('')
            }, {    

                xtype: 'map',
                id: 'dettaglio-map',
                flex: 1,
                mapOptions: {
                    zoomControl: true,
                    zoomControlOptions: {
                      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.DEFAULT
                    },
                    navigationControl: true,
                    navigationControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT
                    },
                    panControl: true,
                    rotateControl: true,
                    streetViewControl: false,
                    mapTypeControl: true,
                    zoom: 12
                },
                listeners: {
                    painted: function(map) {
                        record = map.getData();
                    },

                }
            }
        ],
        record: null
},


updateRecord: function(newRecord) {
    if (newRecord) {
        this.down('#contenuto').setData(newRecord.data);
        this.down('#dettaglio-map').setData(newRecord.data);

        this.down('map').setMapCenter({
            latitude: newRecord.data.latitude,
            longitude: newRecord.data.longitude
        });  

    var map = this.down('map').getMap();
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position = new google.maps.LatLng (newRecord.data.latitude,newRecord.data.longitude),
            map: map,
            title : 'Position = ' + position.toString()
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: marker.title
        });



    marker.setMap(map);  

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    }
}});
```

'MainSearch' composed of SearchBar, SearchList and TweetList'

```
Ext.define('TwitterSearch.view.MainSearch', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
xtype : 'mainsearch',


requires: [
    'TwitterSearch.view.SearchBar',
    'TwitterSearch.view.SearchList',
    'TwitterSearch.view.TweetList'
],


config: {
    fullscreen: true
},
initialize: function(obj, eOpts) {
    this.callParent();
  }});
```

and Controller...

```
Ext.define('TwitterSearch.controller.SearchController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',


config: {
    refs: {
        main: {
            selector  : 'mainview',
            xtype     : 'mainview',
            autoCreate: true
        },
        searchBar: 'searchbar',
        searchList: 'searchlist',
        tweetList: 'tweetlist',
        searchField: 'searchbar > searchfield',
        showContact: 'contact-show',    
    },


    control: {
        searchField: {
            keyup: 'onSearch'
        },


        tweetList: {
            itemtap: 'onTweetTap'
        },


        searchList: {
            select: 'onSearchSelect',
            itemswipe: 'onSearchSwipe'
        },


        'searchlist searchlistitem button': {
            tap: 'onSearchDelete',
        },

        'contact-show button[ui=back]': {
            tap: 'onBackButtonTap'
        }

        }
},


launch: function() {
    Ext.getStore('SearchesStore').load({
        callback: this.onSearchesStoreLoad,
        scope: this
    });
},


/**
 * Called when the searchesStore has been loaded from localStorage. If it is NOT a phone, it will select one of the searches
 * from the list, now that it is loaded.
 * We don't want to select a search when it is loaded on a phone, as it would trigger the tweetList view to display.
 */
onSearchesStoreLoad: function() {
    var search = Ext.getStore('SearchesStore').getAt(0);
    if (!search) {
        this.doSearch("%%");
    }
},



/**
 * Called when a search is selected from the searchList. It sets the store of the tweetList to the tweets() store of the selected
 * search isntance. If the device is a phone, we set the active item to the tweetList. If it is now, we just ensure the tweetList
 * is visible
 */
onSearchSelect: function(list, search) {
    var store = search.tweets();


    this.getTweetList().setStore(store);
    store.load();
},


/**
 * Called when an item in the searchList is swiped. It will show the delete button in the swiped item.
 */
onSearchSwipe: function(dataview, index, target) {
    if (Ext.getStore('SearchesStore').getCount() < 2) {
        return;
    }


    //set the currentDeleteButton so we know what is it to hide it in the listener below
    this.currentDeleteButton = target.getDeleteButton();
    this.currentDeleteButton.show();


    //add a listener to the body, so we can hide the button if the user taps anywhere but the button.
    Ext.getBody().on('tap', this.onBodyTap, this);
},


/**
 * Called when the user taps on the body. Hides the delete button and removes the listener from the body.
 */
onBodyTap: function(e) {
    if (this.currentDeleteButton) {
        this.currentDeleteButton.hide();
    }


    //remove the listener
    Ext.getBody().un('tap', this.onBodyTap, this);
},


/**
 * Called when a user taps on an item in the tweetList. This is used to check if the element the user tapped on is a hashtag.
 * If it is a hashtag, we get watchever that hashtag is and call {@link #doSearch} with it.
 * We could possibly extend this to users, too.
 */
onTweetTap: function(list, index, target, record, e) {
    target = Ext.get(e.target);


    if (target && target.dom && target.hasCls('hashtag')) {
        this.doSearch(target.dom.innerHTML);
    }
    else if (!this.showContact) {
        this.showContact = Ext.create('TwitterSearch.view.contact.Show');
    }
    this.showContact.setRecord(record);


    if (!this.showContact.getParent()) {
        //Ext.Viewport.removeAll(true,true);
        Ext.Viewport.removeAt(0);

        Ext.Viewport.add(this.showContact);
    }


    this.showContact.show();
},

onContactShow: function() {
    Ext.getCmp('viewport').getLayout().getAnimation().setReverse(false);
},



/**
 * Called when a use taps the delete button on a searchList item
 */
onSearchDelete: function(button, e) {
    var item   = button.getParent(),
        search = item.getRecord();


    this.fireAction('destroy', [search, button], 'doDestroy');
},


/**
 * Removes a specified search record from the searches store. The tablet controller subclass has some additional
 * logic to select the nearest saved search
 */
doDestroy: function(search, button) {
    var store = Ext.getStore('SearchesStore');


    store.remove(search);
    store.sync();
    button.hide();
},


/**
 * Called on the keyup event of the search field. If the enter/return key was pressed, it will fire the search action.
 */
onSearch: function(field, e) {
    var keyCode = e.event.keyCode,
        searchField = this.getSearchField();


    //the return keyCode is 13.
    if (keyCode == 13) {
        //fire the search action with the current value of the searchField
        this.fireAction('search', [searchField.getValue()], 'doSearch');

    }
},


/**
 * Called with the search action above. Searches twitter for a specified search term or record
 */
doSearch: function(search) {
    var model         = TwitterSearch.model.SearchModel,
        tweetList     = this.getTweetList(),
        searchList    = this.getSearchList(),
        searchesStore = Ext.getStore('SearchesStore'),
        searchField   = this.getSearchField(),
        query, index;


    // ensure there is a search...
    if (!search) {
        return;
    }


    //ensure the tweetlist is visible
    tweetList.show();


    //check if ths search already exists in the searchesStore
    index = searchesStore.find('query', search);
    if (index != -1) {
        //it exists, so lets just select it
        search = searchesStore.getAt(index);


        searchList.select(search);


        //empty the field and blur it so it looses focus
        searchField.setValue('');
        searchField.blur();


        return;
    }


    //if the passed argument is not an instance of a Search mode, create a new instance
    if (!(search instanceof TwitterSearch.model.SearchModel)) {
        query = search.replace("%20", " ");
        search = new model({
            query: query
        });
    }


    this.scriviCookie('key', query, 100);
    //scriviCookie('key', query, 100);
    //String cookie = this.readCookie('key');
    var x = this.leggiCookie('key');
    alert ("Cookie = " + x);





    //add the new search instance to the searchsStore
    searchesStore.add(search);
    searchesStore.sync();


    // select the new record in the list
    searchList.select(search);


    //empty the field and remove focus from it
    searchField.setValue('');
    searchField.blur();
},

onBackButtonTap: function() {
    this.getMain().setActiveItem(0);
},

scriviCookie: function(nomeCookie,valoreCookie,durataCookie)
{
  var scadenza = new Date();
  var adesso = new Date();
  scadenza.setTime(adesso.getTime() + (parseInt(durataCookie) * 60000));
  document.cookie = nomeCookie + '=' + escape(valoreCookie) + '; expires=' + scadenza.toGMTString() + '; path = /';
},


leggiCookie: function(nomeCookie)
{
  if (document.cookie.length > 0)
  {
    var inizio = document.cookie.indexOf(nomeCookie + "=");
    if (inizio != -1)
    {
      inizio = inizio + nomeCookie.length + 1;
      var fine = document.cookie.indexOf(";",inizio);
      if (fine == -1) fine = document.cookie.length;
      return unescape(document.cookie.substring(inizio,fine));
    }else{
       return "";
    }
  }
  return "";
}});
```

as it is possible to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code in a minimal setup. Just using the TwitterSearch.view.contact.Show and TwitterSearch.controller.SearchController. The button tap is recognized by the controller. 
Since you have not provided the entire code I can not comprehend what the actual problem is.

But I can assume the following:
In your `onTweetTap` you create your showContact view and populate it with data. After that you try to remove the first item from the Ext.Viewport and replace it with your showContact view. That's fine so far. But in your `onBackButtonTap` you only try to set the active item of your main view to the first element. That will not effect the Viewport. So you will not go back to the list. At least I assume that this is what you tried.

I would recommend to use a Ext.navigation.View. That view will handle all transitions. All you have to do is push/pop views. You don't even have to bother about the back button. A navigation view will create one for you and tapping it will automatically return to the previous view.

So all you have to do is create a navigation view and push your tweet list into it. The select listener of the list only needs to create a show view, populate it with record data and push it into the navigation view. That's it.

Comment: I cannot use the navigation view because the dataview so created it takes me all the information of the tweet that they are taken by the database that it is found in the part server. The tweetList is composed from the tweet (inclusive also the retweetses with @, and all the attached links to the tweet) and from the name of the tweet. Clicking on the tweet, it opens the component DataItem of DataView that introduces all the information of the tweet also included the map with the coordinates of the consumer owner of the tweet.I have made reference to the example TouchTweets of Sencha Touch.

Comment: I still don't see why you can not use the navigation view. Basically it's just another container around all your other containers. It does not matter where the data come from. Creation of your components won't change...

Comment: ...Anyway as I said: it seems that the problem is in your onTweetTap and onBackButtonTap methods. In your onTweetTap method you remove the first (and probably only) item from the Ext.Viewport and add the showContact view. But you don't change the view on our Ext.Viewport in your onBackButtonTap. You only set the activeItem of your main view. That does not effect the viewport. Add the main view to the viewport in onBackButtonTap. That could do the trick.

Comment: in the onbackButtonTap i tried with these instruction:   Ext.Viewport.removeAt(0);
Ext.Viewport.add(this.getMain);    well, it visualize an empty view.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot use the navigation view because the dataview so created it takes me all the information of the tweet that they are taken by the database that it is found in the part server. The tweetList is composed from the tweet (inclusive also the retweetses with @, and all the attached links to the tweet) and from the name of the tweet. Clicking on the tweet, it opens the component DataItem of DataView that introduces all the information of the tweet also included the map with the coordinates of the consumer owner of the tweet.I have made reference to the example TouchTweets of Sencha Touch. Then who can help me???

Answer (score 0):

in the onbackButtonTap i tried with these instruction: Ext.Viewport.removeAt(0); Ext.Viewport.add(this.getMain); well, it visualize an empty view.